# Asking about how our brain interpret a procedurally generated squarish rainbow picture

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm kind of lost here, usually I do my search on my own first but here, idk, I don't even really know what I should type in Google to look for answer.

[image: Squarish rainbow]

Basically, I got this image I generated myself and I noticed that our eyes/brain interprets/see **two crossing diagonal lines**.

But they do not exist. The way I generated this picture is, the inefficient way, by creating the outer square then overwriting them successively with smaller square of different colors. *There is no line.*

I think it might be due to proximity with other colors but I'm not sure.

Where should I ask this very question ideally?

**EDIT:** I got a bit inspired and search for "Brain perception lines illusion" but I haven't found my answer yet, plus I'd like an explanation on this very case if possible.

Comment: What would be the question you want to ask exactly?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Why do we see lines where there is no actual lines there.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft (what is the scientific explanation behind it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [Cognitive Sciences](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) site. Please note that it does not have many active experts.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that here: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/10599/8788 . Also, for those interested, I think I _may_ have answered my own question! (But I'm not sure yet!)